# Memory Leak When Opening Data Frame With RDCOMClient

Tags: r, memory-leaks, rdcomclient

I am experimenting with using the RDCOMClient package to open a dataframe on the fly into Excel. I have functional code which will open a dataframe into Excel, however the issue I am running into is that the memory resources from loading the data into Excel are not being released by rsession.exe when the code completes. Even after closing the Excel application the memory resources are not released. Is there something I am missing, that I could use to release the memory from rsession.exe? The only way I have been able to release the memory is by closing out of RStudio and opening it back up again.

Code for the function

```
in.xl <- function(data, headers = TRUE, rownames = FALSE) {
  require(RDCOMClient)

  # Attempt to coerce non dataframe data into a dataframe
  if (!is.data.frame(data)) {
    data <- as.data.frame(data)
  }

  # Set row range for data
  if (headers == TRUE) {
    d.row.start <- 2
    d.row.end <- nrow(data) + 1
  } else {
    d.row.start <- 1
    d.row.end <- nrow(data)
  }

  # Set column range for data
  if (rownames == TRUE) {
    d.col.start <- 2
    d.col.end <- ncol(data) + 1
  } else {
      d.col.start <- 1
      d.col.end <- ncol(data)
    }

  # Create COM Connection to Excel
  xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
  xlWB <- xlApp[["Workbooks"]]$Add()
  xlSheet <- xlWB$Sheets(1)

  # Check if headers should be included
  if (headers == TRUE) {

    # Create a dataframe from headers
    headers <- t(as.data.frame(colnames(data)))

    # Set range for header values
    startCell <- xlSheet$Cells(1, d.col.start)
    endCell <- xlSheet$Cells(1, d.col.end)
    rng <- xlSheet$Range(startCell, endCell)

    # Add headers to Excel sheet
    rng[["Value"]] <- asCOMArray(headers)

    # Remove header dataframe
    rm(headers)
  }

  # Check if rownames should be included
  if(rownames == TRUE) {

    # Create dataframe from row names
    if (is.null(rownames(data))) {
      rnames = as.data.frame(1:nrow(data))
    } else {
        rnames = as.data.frame(rownames(data))
      }

    # Set range for row name values
    startCell <- xlSheet$Cells(d.row.start, 1)
    endCell <- xlSheet$Cells(d.row.end, 1)
    rng <- xlSheet$Range(startCell, endCell)

    # Add row names to Excel sheet
    rng[["Value"]] <- asCOMArray(rnames)

    # Remove row name dataframe
    rm(rnames)
  } 

  xlApp[["ScreenUpdating"]] <- FALSE

  nblocks <- ceiling(nrow(data) / 2000)
  pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = nblocks, initial = 0, style = 3, width = 20)
  data.start <- d.row.start
  block <- 1
  d.row.end <- d.row.start
  df.row.start <- 1

  while(d.row.end < nrow(data)) {
    d.row.end <- d.row.start + 1999
    df.row.end <- df.row.start + 1999

    if (d.row.end > nrow(data) + data.start) {
      d.row.end <- nrow(data) + data.start - 1
    }

    if (df.row.end > nrow(data)) {
      df.row.end <- nrow(data)
    }

    xlApp[["StatusBar"]] <- paste("Processing block", block, "of", nblocks)

    # Set range for data values
    rng <- xlSheet$Range(xlSheet$Cells(d.row.start, d.col.start), xlSheet$Cells(d.row.end, d.col.end))

    # Add data to Excel sheet
    rng[["Value"]] <- asCOMArray(data[df.row.start:df.row.end, ])

    d.row.start <- d.row.end + 1
    df.row.start <- df.row.end + 1

    if (block != nblocks) {
      block <- block + 1
    }

    # update the progress bar with the current value
    setTxtProgressBar(pb,block)
    rm(rng, vals)
    gc()
  }

  xlApp[["StatusBar"]] <- "Formatting Columns..."

  # Auto adjust column widths
  for(c in 1:d.col.end) {
    col <- xlSheet$Columns(c)
    col[["EntireColumn"]]$AutoFit()
  }

  xlApp[["StatusBar"]] <- ""
  xlApp[["ScreenUpdating"]] <- TRUE

  # Show Excel application
  xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE

  gc()
}
```

Code to generate a large dataframe for testing. (Makes it easier to see the memory usage issue when looking at the rsession.exe process in Task Manager)

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(20, sample(replicate(10, paste(sample(LETTERS, 15, rep = TRUE), collapse = "")), 100000, rep = TRUE)))

in.xl(df)
```

Comment: While I do reproduce your issue, do note rsession.exe is a byproduct of RStudio and a handful of [posts](https://www.google.com/search?q=rstudio&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=rstudio+rsession+memory) have raised this issue. In fact, even Rgui.exe retains this memory size with your code. It may be once an R session allocates memory from OS it does not return it but leaves it unused.

Comment: So, are you facing performance issues or just looking at the memory size? Also, had you run `RScript /path/to/code.R` via command line (CMD or PowerShell), no memory footprint remains as no R session persists.

Comment: The goal of the script is to have a function that can be called from within rstudio which will open a dataframe in Excel without saving out to a file first. The main problem is that each time the function is called, more and more memory is used, until the system has no memory left to allocate.

Comment: Again, RStudio is not necessary for script to run. The Excel file does output if you call script at command line. Consider doing so with many runs of function to avoid session holding onto memory.

Comment: Calling the script from command line may be a good workaround for the problem, however it does not solve the problem entirely. The goal is to have the ability to call the function from the console in RStudio, so that there is a quick method to simply open a dataframe in Excel for easy viewing and verification. Needing to open a separate application to call the function would be a bit too cumbersome and somewhat defeats the purpose.

Comment: If I just want to quickly open some data in excel I usually just create a temporary file.  Is there a reason you can't create a file?  I have a little function I use to open things in excel is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I have another function that I use as well which will open dataframes in Excel by saving out to a temp file. The purpose behind trying to open the dataframe in Excel without saving to a temp file, is to prevent inadvertently leaving behind temporary files on the system which may potentially contain sensitive information. I am aware there are ways to automatically remove those files, but I would prefer to not save them out in the first place if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the package callr. With the following code, the memory is released :

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(20, sample(replicate(10, paste(sample(LETTERS, 15, rep = TRUE), collapse = "")), 1000000, rep = TRUE)))

library(callr)
callr::r(func = in.xl, args = list(data = df))
```